# Junit xml results only contain scenarios which are executed on rerun

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Cucumber project which uses Junit and Maven together. I also added Maven Surefire Plugin to enable rerun and parallel execution. That part at pom xml is below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Cucumber.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But when rerun is executed, junit xml file is generated with the scenarios that run on rerun. To give an example, if i execute 61 scenarios and 1 of 61 scenarios fail on the rerun, junit xml file contains only 1 scenario. 60 scenarios that passed before the last rerun are not added to xml results. Xml file is generated where the path i gave below:

**junit:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.xml**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true, features = { "src/test/resources/features" }, glue = {
        "stepDefinitions" }, monochrome = true, tags = "not @ignore", plugin = { "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-reports", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.xml", "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" }, dryRun = false)

public class TestRunnerCucumber {

}
```

Example run result:

[image: Example Run Result]

Xml result of the example run:

[image: Example Xml Result]

How do i add the scenarios that passed on the first run to the junit xml results?

Comment: I would suggest to first upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to the most recent version ...

Comment: Updated to 3.0.0-M5 version, but still getting the same xml result.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

You are using Surefire to rerun tests. From the perspective of Cucumber running the tests again is the same as running Cucumber again with fewer tests. This means the output from the first run is replaced with the results from the rerun.

Only Surefire knows that tests have been rerun. So you'll have to rely on Surefires reports when using Surefires rerun ability. These are also located in the `target` folder.